# Doing aggregations on when method in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Data**

---

```
first_name,id,age

abc,1,53

bcd,2,68

abc,3,68
```

Made this data into `personDF` dataframe

```
personDF.groupBy("id").agg(when(lower($"first_name")==="abc",min($"age")).otherwise(max($"age")).alias("min_age")).show()
```

I want to get the min age and max age based on the when condition. It's not working.

Please let me know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by 'first_name' column for this to work:

```
df.groupBy("first_name").agg(when(lower($"first_name")==="abc",min($"age")).otherwise(max($"age")).alias("min_age")).show()

+----------+-------+
|first_name|min_age|
+----------+-------+
|       abc|     53|
|       bcd|     68|
+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an aggregate function on the same column on which you are grouping the dataframe. This will not work as one group will have only one value of the column on which you have grouped.

Please check out this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#groupBy(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) for better understanding.